# Overheating problem with dell n5110 Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dell, overheating

My dell laptop (N5110) gets extremely overheated with Ubuntu till the point that it shutdowns by itself although it works perfectly fine with windows. I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I have heard that many dell laptops have this problem with Ubuntu. Can anyone suggest how this can be fixed or even if a fix is available or not?

[Edit]

This is the output of `sudo lshw -c display` on my laptop.

```
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list 

rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:56 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f6000000-f607ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:54 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: You should report a bug instead.

Comment: As this model has multiple variant, Could you add output of `sudo lshw -c display` to the question. So Laptop with similar graphic card may use same solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who have the same problem with dell laptops, i solved it by installing bumblebee, apparently there was some problem with the GPU drivers, the instructions can be found here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation